# How to fix fatal error when running PHP 7.1 break not in loop

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

Excel files can be downloaded and edited when server using PHP 5 but it's error in PHP 7. It shows fatal error break not in the loop

I already try to remove break in the loop but it doesn't work.

```
public static function TYPE($value = NULL) {
    $value  = self::flattenArrayIndexed($value);
    if (is_array($value) && (count($value) > 1)) {
        $a = array_keys($value);
        $a = array_pop($a);
        //  Range of cells is an error
        if (self::isCellValue($a)) {
            return 16;
        //  Test for Matrix
        } elseif (self::isMatrixValue($a)) {
            return 64;
        }
    } elseif(empty($value)) {
        //  Empty Cell
        return 1;
    }
    $value  = self::flattenSingleValue($value);

    if (($value === NULL) || (is_float($value)) || (is_int($value))) {
            return 1;
    } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
            return 4;
    } elseif(is_array($value)) {
            return 64;
            break;
            //return false; 
    } elseif(is_string($value)) {
        //  Errors
        if ((strlen($value) > 0) && ($value{0} == '#')) {
            return 16;
        }
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}   //  function TYPE()
```

Comment: You don't have any loops. Just remove the `break` you have in there.

Comment: Is `$value{0} == '#'` supposed to have `[]`'s instead?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If you see a fatal error, there should be something written to the server's error log

Answer (score 3):

The only break in your code is in an unreachable secton of code (after return) so feel free to remove it.

Break statement can only be inside any loop or switch block (same with continue).
If you have many problems with your code since upgrading to higher version of PHP i suggest to scan your source code with automated tool such as [PHP CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and then fix the reported errors.